# JQuery post method is always redirecting to the Index() method in c# MVC and the parameters passed are not reflected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-post

I am trying to call one of the action method defined in my controller when the value in the drop down is changed. I am also passing the changed value as parameter to the action method. I tried changing the action method name just to confirm but it always hits index() and the parameter passed is always received as null.

```
$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $('#dropdown').val();
    var url = "@Url.Action("Index","Controller")" + selectedValue;
    $.post(url);
});
```

---

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    //some code
}
```

---

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "Home",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: $.post( url, { argumentName: selectedValue} ); for the null bit

Comment: @artm I tried this as well but that did not solve my issue.

Comment: this? @Url.Action("Index","Controller")" + "?id=" + selectedValue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Url.Action("Index","Controller")" + "?id=" + selectedValue;  worked. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a `/` in the URL you are creating:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $('#dropdown').val();
    var url = "@Url.Action("Index","Controller")" + "/" + selectedValue;
    $.post(url);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidG. I tried this but I am still getting it as null.

Comment: Can you post more of your controller code (and possibly the routing config too)

Comment: If you add in `alert(url);` before the post operation, what does the URL look like?

Comment: Thank you David it is working fine after implementing @artm changes